# fullcalendar.io v5 - change color of first day of event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want to change the color of the first day of the background event. For example, the first day red and the other days will be default. How to achieve this? I found the function

eventDidMount: function (event){ },

but I don't know how to select the first day and swap the color. Someone can help?

I attach the JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/eud9wcos/

Comment: Please add your code here

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color of the individual events using **backgroundColor** property of the event. You need to add this property to the first day event in the json data.

```
events: [{
                "title": "03.11.21",
                "start": "2021-11-03T15:00:00",
                "end": "2021-11-03T15:00:00",
                "display": "background",
                "allDay": true,
                "backgroundColor":"red"
                 },
                 {
                "title": "08.11-12.11",
                "start": "2021-11-08",
                "end": "2021-11-13",
                "display": "background",
                "allDay": true
                }],
```

Also you do not have to set the eventDidMount callback anymore, as rest of the background events will switch to a default color which is your requirement.

Please refer the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) for more information.